# Unity dialogue system for multiple dialogues in the scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

Basically my player will walk through the scene and in some specific points he will collide with a collider that triggers a dialogue, it’s actually a text box that display some hints to pass to the next level (I know it’s not exactly a dialogue but I hope you could understand). So I used this tutorial by Brackets for dialogue system. The problem is that if I had to put multiples points in the scene it won’t work, it will only work for the first point I collide, or it will display another text from the other point I have yet not collided. I haven’t found another tutorial on Youtube for multiple dialogues in the scene.
[Tutorial Link](https://youtu.be/_nRzoTzeyxU?si=KanK8MACTm-hYIE-)

**ColliderDialogue.cs attached to Canvas and a point collider:**

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ColliderDialogue : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject DialogueBox;
    DialogueManager dialogueManager;
    DialogueTrigger dialogueTrigger;
    public bool PlayingDialogue = false;

    private void Awake()
    {
        dialogueManager = FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>();
        dialogueTrigger = FindObjectOfType<DialogueTrigger>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Start()
    {
        DialogueBox.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            dialogueManager.DisplayNextSentence();
        }
        if(dialogueManager.playingDialogue == true)
        {
            PlayingDialogue = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            DialogueBox.SetActive(true);
            dialogueTrigger.TriggerDialogue();
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
```

**DialogueManager.cs attached to a empty game object ‘DialogueManager’:**

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class DialogueManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject DialogueBox;
    public TextMeshProUGUI nameText;
    public TextMeshProUGUI dialogueText;
    private Queue<string> sentences;

    public bool playingDialogue = false;

    public bool endDialogueBox = false;
    void Start()
    {
        sentences = new Queue<string>();
    }

    public void StartDialogue (Dialogue dialogue)
    {
        playingDialogue=true;

        nameText.text = dialogue.name;

        sentences.Clear();

        foreach (string sentence in dialogue.sentences)
        {
            sentences.Enqueue(sentence);
        }

        Time.timeScale = 0;

        DisplayNextSentence();
    }

    public void DisplayNextSentence()
    {
        if(sentences.Count == 0)
        {
            EndDialogue();
            return;
        }

        string sentence = sentences.Dequeue();
        StopAllCoroutines();
        StartCoroutine(TypeSentence(sentence));
    }

    IEnumerator TypeSentence(string sentence)
    {
        dialogueText.text = "";
        foreach (char letter in sentence.ToCharArray())
        {
            dialogueText.text += letter;
            yield return null;
        }

    }

    public void EndDialogue()
    {
        Debug.Log("End of conversation");
        DialogueBox.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1;
        endDialogueBox = true;
    }

}
```

**Dialogue.cs:**

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Dialogue 
{
    public string name;
    [TextArea(3, 10)]
    public string[] sentences;
}

**DialogueTrigger.cs attached to point collider:**

    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DialogueTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Dialogue dialogue;

    public void TriggerDialogue()
    {
        FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>().StartDialogue(dialogue);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: correct because the manager only has 1 set of sentences but you have all the information you need to make many, if you wanted. So the question then is, what is stopping you from turning it into something not 1 per scene, but many

Comment: You mean that didn't work collider enter or another.
Please explain detail with image 

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem is on your ColliderDialogue class, where your dialogueTrigger is been filled by the FindObjectOfType function, but that function returns one instance based on your scene, if you will have more than one, it could be the same across all your objects and for sure the data that goes to the DialogueManager will be the same, so i'll recommend that your varialble dialogueTrigger should be filled with the inspector making it public or add [SerializeField] if you need it private, then drag and drop the correct one.